# Basic Calculation Python

Tags: python-3.8

Input the math expression such as 3+2*{1+2*[-4/(8-6)+7]} make the python program calculate. The problem is, it gives no output. How to fix this problem.

```
while True:
    try:
        express = input()
        express.replace("[", "(")
        express.replace("{", "(")
        express.replace("]", ")")
        express.replace("}", ")")
        print(eval(express))
    except:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Update:
After each replacement, we must update the expression, otherwise the change will only reflect to the given expression & after each replace statement it will change and only modify the given expression

```
while True:
    try:
        express = input()
        x = express.replace("[", "(")
        y = x.replace("{", "(")
        z = y.replace("]", ")")
        w = z.replace("}", ")")
        print(eval(w))
    except:
        break
```

Comment: The input with "[" "{" is the requirement of this question

Comment: This answer could use some explanatory text.

Comment: instead, you should redefine the `express` variable to make the program more efficient, instead of constantly creating new variables.